# How to use gethostbyname in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, gethostbyname

I'm trying to use the function gethostbyname, but my code:

```
int handleTCP(char *hostname, char* portNo){

    struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname(hostname);

    ...

}
```

Keeps returning:

```
21: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my syntax?

thanks

Comment: if Evan's answer was not what was the problem: show us more code, especially whether line-number 21 is one of the ones you show us.

Comment: Have you definitely got `#include <sys/socket.h>` at the top of your code?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: netdb.h is all you need for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `#include <netdb.h>`. Because you didn't include this file, you are running into the "default int" rule. Basically, in C, if a function has no prototype, it is assumed to be:

`int function_name();` in other words "returns an int, takes unknown number of parameters".

Properly declaring the function prototype (in this case by including the header) will avoid this.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it. Silly mistake by me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include `netdb.h` header file, so that compiler knows nothing about `gethostbyname` function and assumes that it returns integer. Then it complaints because in that case you would have converted integer to a pointer. You need to include a header to provide compiler with correct type information.